# Recover android after flashing bootloader

Tags: android, bootloader

I recently unlocked my Motorola Razor i XT890 and followed [mattlgroff](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4370056) tutorial to root the device.

```
sudo ./files/fastboot.osx flash boot ./files/razr_i_boot_insecured.img                                                                                                                                                                    rvm:
Password:
     sending 'boot' (11264 KB)... OKAY [  1.393s]
                writing 'boot'... OKAY [  1.839s]
```

then the device reboots, and I am not able to get to `bootloader`

[image: Warning]

If anybody has any idea how to recover this device that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You should try this site - http://android.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you try to get into the Bootloader? To get into the Bootloader power off the device. Press vol-down and power until it vibrates. When it vibrates release the power button and keep the vol-down pressed.

Maybe you have the wrong timing ;)

Comment: It is like there is no bootloader, it gets to this warning then no further. After a while it restarts after a few minutes to the same screen.

Comment: Did you tried it? It seems fine, that's the normal screen after unlock